# Odoo - ORM retrieve translated name from product.template

Tags: odoo-10

I want to retrieve the name from product.template:

```
print self.env['product.template'].search([("id", "=", id), ]).name
```

How do I get translated name in ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the language code in context to get specific product name in that language. Make sure that language has been loaded in your server before using it. I did some changes in your code to get the product name in German / Duetsch language.

```
print self.env['product.template'].with_context({'lang': 'de_DE'}).search([("id", "=", id)]).name
```

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: I think that language should be loaded first in database. Only loaded language will work in your suggested code.

Comment: @AjayChauhan Thanks for the suggestion to improve answer. :)